# how to show legend name if no data is there for the particular series in the legend ?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

In my chart, I am displaying months on x axis and percentage of touchpoint qsns answered in y axis . based on the percentage , the legend series are :
full day complete,half day complete, full day incomplete and half day incomplete . 
now where there is no data  then in the legend, SSRS is  not displaying the series name and only other series are displayed .
My requirement is that i want all series name to display even if no data was there in the table . i need to know if i can use a case statement in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table and fill the table with all the dates within the date range that you want data for. Then update the temp table with the values for each date that exists in the data. Then selected from the temp table at the end of the stored procedure, and that will ensure you have a value for each date. See below for an example:

```
DECLARE  @StartDate datetime = '6/1/2015',
        @EndDate datetime = '6/30/2015'

DECLARE @DayRange int = (select DateDiff(day,@StartDate,@EndDate)) 

--This can be done differently, I made this negative
SET @DayRange = - @DayRange

--This is your temp table that will have all your dates in the range
DECLARE @Temp Table
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
DataDate DateTime,
DataValue int
)

--Fill the temp table with all the dates
WHILE(@DayRange < 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Temp 
SELECT DateAdd(day,@DayRange,@EndDate),0
SET @DayRange = @DayRange + 1
END

--Check out your temp table
SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

Comment: thnks .. but will dis work ..i want the series  name in the legend to display for which there was no data  . is there any other alternative to this ?

Comment: in the query above I'm creating a 0 value record for all dates this should create a value for every day in the series. Do you have an example of the data you are working with? I could give you a better approach.